# If a Firebase client is temporarily disconnected, will changes be sent separately and in the right order?

Tags: firebase

I am developing an app to show real time prices of cryptocurrencies. I am using Firebase open data set.

If my app suddenly gets disconnected from network (no carrier connection or wifi), then on re-connection, will Firebase sends all the price changes that app missed while it was disconnected? For example, my app got disconnected at 1PM and then re-connects back at 1:30pm and lets say Bitcoin price changed 15 times during this period. So when I connect back at 1:30PM, will I get all the 15 prices changes and in the right order?

Comment: Your question about discrepancies in cryptocurrencies are probably off-topic, or at least are questions that are best directed to the owners of the websites you mention. I've edited them out, so as to discourage further downvotes (the remaining question is IMO okay). If you believe the discrepancy question is a technical issue, you will need to be much more detailed, and in any case it should be a separate question. Personally I still think it is o/t.

Comment: Have you looked at the Firebase docs to see whether it will do the updates individually following a reconnection? Or, you could just try it!

Comment: @halfer - Yes i did and it says that it does. Although i am creating a graph based on the prices coming in. What i did to test was i switched off wifi on mac while the app was running on my iphone plotting the graph. When i switched on the wifi, it did get the prices but the graph shape was not same as the one on my phone, which i suspect is because Firebase did send the prices (which got missed while it was disconnected) but in wrong order. Hence my question. I am gonna do some logging of message timestamps to test this theory as well.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case, probably not.

Firebase focuses on getting your app synchronized with the most current value. If a given node changes a lot, it's going to catch your client up on the state rather than playing back a log of change events.

In other words, the open data set that you are using is not designed to create a time series chart. Instead it's designed to show you the most recent value.

To accomplish your goal you need a Firebase that synchronizes historical data instead of just the simple value. For example, [Firepad](http://www.firepad.io/), a collaborative text editor, uses a technique called [operational transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation) to solve a similar problem.